# Windows Phone 8.1 Live Tile custom branding?

Tags: c#, live-tile, windows-phone-8.1

Is it possible to define a specific text in the branding attribute instead of just the name or logo of the application like it was in Windows Phone 8?
I'm trying to add text to TileSquare150x150IconWithBadge tile template, but with no success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already can change the title of the application on the live tile. And you can render pretty much everything you want on the live tile with the `WriteableBitmap`. So what is your question?

Comment: Where can I change the title? That's what I've tried to do but I haven't found out how. 
It was simple in windows 8 when there was the title tag but now it's gone.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good sample showing how to do all the various tile updated here and this includes images: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148/view/SourceCode